# not getting how to deal with redis and php

Tags: php, redis

I have gone though the tutorial of redis and php. i am currently using predis. I have three files named `form.php`, `submit.php`, and `mail.php`. in `form.php` i have a simple form. in `submit.php` i have written a simple code for display something. and in`mail.php`. i have written some code for sending mail. when i submit form in `form.php` then it should go on `submit.php`. and `mail.php` should start in background. I have written some thing like this:

`submit.php`

```
      $client = new \Predis\Client();
  $client->select(4);
      $client->lpush('xxxx',$x['to']);
 $arrOutput=shell_exec('php mail.php');
    print_r($arrOutput);
```

in `mail.php`

```
  require '/var/www/predis/autoload.php';
        \Predis\Autoloader::register();

echo "hi";

require_once('Services/Notification.php');

$client = new \Predis\Client();
      $client->select(4);

$u=$client->blpop('xxxx',0);

var_dump($u);

notification_on_signup($u[1]);
```

then please tell me how should i configure this thing. so that i can send mail.php in bakground

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you get any error messages? It's unclear to me what your problem is. Can you please define 'this thing' in your last sentence?

Comment: actually what i want is that i want to run `mail.php` in background and `submit.php` in foreground.

Comment: And where is the problem with that? Also why don't you just do both things in the submit script? Are you expecting long load times due to the mailing process?

Comment: yep i dont want long load time. i just want to display next response and want to send mail in bg

Comment: @lord_linus have you heard about ajax?

Comment: @h4b0 yep but what i want is that first submit.php should be executed and after completion of `submit.php` then mail.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want very easily. In most modern JS framework you can submit not only an asynchronous call to server, but also a callback function for success/failure.

Assuming you use `jQuery` it would similar to this one:

```
$.post('submit.php', function(response) {
    //do you want to do anything with response string?
    //do it now
    $.post('mail.php', function(response) {

    });
});
```

Check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).